# Can't make text bold in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I want to make sum in pdf bold. I tried next :

```
var phraseTotal = new Paragraph();
phraseTotal.Font.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
phraseTotal.Add(new Chunk(string.Format("Total earned for period {0} - {1} : ", invoice.FromDate.ToShortDateString(), invoice.ToDate.ToShortDateString())));
phraseTotal.Add(new Chunk("£" + Math.Round(invoice.TotalAmount / 100.0, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));

list.Add(phraseTotal);
```

Also tried to add to Paragraph some font... Tried to change Paragraph to Phrase...

But always this sum is invisible or not rendered in pdf.

---

Update: the problem is in the list. If I apply the same to the object that is not in the list - it's bold.

Comment: Just an FYI - WKHTMLToPDF, via Codaxy and Conversion from HTML is the right way to do this.  Its also free.  I struggled with many ways of doing it for a month or so, until I found WKHTMLToPDF.  I won't ever use anything else again.

Comment: @Mr.B WKHTMLToPDF also has some problems, but now i use itextSharp

Comment: I used ITextSharp as well.  If you're starting from scratch ITextSharp is good, but it doesn't obey CSS properly.  You have to embed style sheets.  Instead of building new things like Paragraphs.  Its easiest to simply get it looking right in HTML and pumping that through the converter.

Comment: @Mr.B I am agree, but currently i just need to make text bold... i have no time for rewriting now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("Concentrate:", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE)));
Chunk c2 = new Chunk("In order to remember something you need to learn it. Learning is possible only if you pay enough attention to it. You will retain information for a longer period of time only if you concentrate properly at the time of learning.", new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLUE)));

Pharagraph p2 = new Pharagraph();
p2.Add(c1);
p2.Add(c2);

ListItem firstRecommend = new ListItem(p2);
```

This sample is from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227686/3917754 .

Problem that i was able to produce was caused that i didn't create new `ListItem` but at once add `Paragraph` to list. With `List Item` everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I would just go this route, instead of bothering with writing code to do it:

```
private MemoryStream createPDF(string html)
{
    MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);            

    // step 2:
    // we create a writer that listens to the document
    // and directs a XML-stream to a file
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);

    // step 3: we create a worker parse the document
    HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

    // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
    document.Open();
    worker.StartDocument();

    // step 5: parse the html into the document
    worker.Parse(reader);

    // step 6: close the document and the worker
    worker.EndDocument();
    worker.Close();
    document.Close();

    return msOutput;
}
```

Comment: `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated. It might not be a good idea to use it in new code.